# Python filtering non alphanumeric not working properly

Tags: python, file, filter, alphanumeric

I have a text file with random letters,numbers and characters in it. I have to remove the special characters and only end up with alphanumeric ones, while printing the process.

Text file is like this:

```
fkdjks97#!%&jd
28e8uw99...
```

and so on

For some reason it's printing:

```
Line read' ,,s.8,ymsw5w-86    
 '
' ,,s.8,ymsw5w-86
 '->' <filter object at 0x0000020406BC8550> '
```

These should go on only 2 lines, instead of 4. Like this:

Line read' ,,s.8,ymsw5w-86'

' ,,s.8,ymsw5w-86' -> 's8ymsw5w86'

My attempt:

```
file1 = open(textfile1,"r")

while True:
    line = file1.readline()
    line2 = filter(str.isalnum,line)
    print("Line read'", str(line), "'")
    print("'", str(line), "'->'", line2, "'")

    if len(line) == 0:
        break
```

Comment: In Python 3 `filter` is an object that needs materialising into a sequence object such as a `list` or a `str`, e.g `list(filter(...`, or `''.join(filter(...`

Answer (score 3):

`filter()` is an iterator object; you'll need to actually iterate over it to pull out the results.

In this case, you want a string back, so you could use `str.join()` to do the iteration and put everything back into a single string:

```
line2 = ''.join(filter(str.isalnum, line))
```

Note that you shouldn't really need to use a `while True` loop with `file1.readline()` calls. You can use a `for` loop directly over the file to get the lines by replacing the `while True`, `line = file1.readline()` and `if len(line) == 0: break` lines with:

```
for line in file1:
    # ...
```

Comment: filter() returns an iterator object ... true only for Python 3

Comment: @quant: and the OP is using Python 3, which is why they see the `<filter object at 0x0000020406BC8550> output.

Comment: @quant: The code provided by OP is certainly for `Python 3`.

Comment: @quant: but as Martijn explained, the `<filter object` is only in Python 3.  In Python 2, it'd just be a list, in which case the OP wouldn't have seen `<filter object` in the first place.  For the OP to be using Python 2, there would need to be a `filter` shadowing (such as is done when using certain 2/3 compatibility libraries, but that's thinking zebra not horse.)

Comment: @quant: the *specific error mode here* shows it is Python 3. `filter()` in Python two would have resulting in a list of strings, each an individual character.

Comment: I am using Python 3.5

Comment: Why is my printing output putting the ' (apostrophe?) on a new line? How can i get it on the same line? Everything should go on 2 lines only, now it's going on 4 lines.

Comment: @Jaakkath you are printing a string with a newline as part of the value. Either remove the newline (use `str.strip()` or `str.rstrip()` for example) or use `repr()` instead of `str()` to print the *representation* of the string value. The latter will include quotes, and special characters like newlines are represented you an escape sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for a regex solution:

```
import re
rx = re.compile(r'[^A-Za-z]+')

# some sample line
line = 'fkdjks97#!%&jd'

# and then later on
line = rx.sub('', line)
print(line)
```

Which yields

```
# fkdjksjd
```

---

Putting this in a `with...` construct, you might be using

```
with open(textfile1, "r") as fp:
    line = rx.sub('', fp.readline())
    print(line)
```